# Why jQuery UI Sortable isn't working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i'm trying to implement on my page the jQuery UI Sortable plugin, but it isn't working.
Can anyone help me with this error? I think it might be something simple that is escaping me.

the link to preview is: http://jsbin.com/ebixi3
the link to jsbin edit is: http://jsbin.com/ebixi3/edit

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: u want me to read the whole code... ??? R u serious..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ebixi3 to see it working... you have the preview button one the upper left... Learn JSBin.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of your other plugins interfering with jQuery UI, [here's an updated/working version](http://jsbin.com/ebixi3/5).

I literally did *nothing* but remove this plugin to make it work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microdual.com/js/jquery.jqbrowser-0.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh Nick, at the same time again! ahahaha
Thanks ;) i will mark your answer as right!

Comment: @CuSS -What is that plugin for anyway? something `$.support` and `$.browser` don't already have?

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @CuSS - I would actually stray away from browser detection...what are you using it for?

Comment: I use the plugin here: http://www.microdual.com/assets/js/main.js (!$.browser.msie() and something like this)

Comment: @CuSS -It sounds like you want `if(!$.support.opacity)` in those 2 cases...this will be true for IE6-8, not for 9.  Since you're fading I'd go with browser detection like this :)

Comment: hmm... i will try, thanks again Nick! do you have facebook? i must add you, god damn!

Comment: I need jQbrowser here too : http://ajax.microdual.com/js/jquery.microdual-1.0.0.min.js
how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered two problems:

- the comment after `<!--[if IE 6]>` ends the conditional comment! So the JS-code will be evaluated in other browsers than IE6 too!
- JqBrowser plugin conflicts somehow with the sortable plugin

Answer (score 0):

OK, discovered!
The plugin JqBrowser (dont know why), is making conflit with jQuery UI Sortable plugin...

Removed this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microdual.com/js/jquery.jqbrowser-0.2.0.min.js"></script>
```